# AddAuthenticationSchemes uses OR, is there a way to make it use AND?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // Other schemes here

    var userAndApplicationJwtAuthPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes("UserJwt")
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes("ApplicationJwt")
        .Build();
     options.AddPolicy("UserAndApplicationAuthentication", userAndApplicationJwtAuthPolicy);
});
```

The key part is the `AddAuthenticationScheme` calls.

With this code, if I send in a UserJwt OR an ApplicationJwt it passes the call along to the controller.  I need this to return a 401 unless BOTH are provided.  Effectively I am looking for a way to enforce both schemes in one policy.  (NOTE if both are provided, it does create a `ClaimsPrinciple` for both.)

I am hoping I can call `AddRequirement` or something similar to enforce that both are present.

**Is there a way to change `AddAuthenticationSchemes` to require BOTH schemes?**

NOTE: I also tried `.AddAuthenticationSchemes("UserJwt", "ApplicationJwt")` and it still does OR.
NOTE 2: I know I can add separate policies for each, then use two `[Authorize(Policy = "PolicyName")]` attributes (one for each policy) on the controller.  However, I am hopping to make the default of `[Authorize]` be both schemes together.

Comment: I'm wondering, if you have 2 JWTs, who is the user? To which Id does `Controller.User.Identity.Name` correspond?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I set `ClaimsPrincipal.PrimaryIdentitySelector` to ensure that UserJwt gets set as the primary identity.  (So `Controller.User.Identity.Name` will always be the UserJwt.)  But they are both available in `User.Identities`.